# dynamic path NavLink React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

I'm looking for a way to make the "to" property of NavLink react dynamic.

```
let url = 'localhost'=='localhost'? 'foo':'';
<Router>
 <NavLink to={url+'/'}>Home</NavLink>
</Router>
```

Work but with each new render react it adds a new url to the existing one.
http://localhost/foo
After render
http://localhost/foo/foo ...

thanks

Comment: Not related to your question but if you dont plan to change the value of the url in your code you should use `const` and not `let`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting a slash in FRONT of the URL, too...

```
<NavLink to={'/'+url+'/'}>Home</NavLink>
```

Having no URL in front means "relative to the current path", while a URL in front means "relative to the domain name"

Or maybe a better way to acheive the same result in your case would be to put the slash in front of `foo` - eg:

```
let url = 'localhost'=='localhost'? '/foo':''; // <=== added slash 
<Router>
 <NavLink to={url+'/'}>Home</NavLink>
</Router>
```

Comment: yes, the second solution is better and more refined